# How to test an embedded Deezer app?

Tags: deezer

How can I test a Deezer app built to be embedded in Deezer website or mobile app (like Digster or 'Deezer By...")?

I understand this kind of app is similar to a standalone one, but my app would involve specific interactions with the embedded player for which I need to build a proof of concept.

Any sandbox mode or developer program available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to your own Deezer app considered as an inapp by this URL: http://www.deezer.com/app/[ID of your creatd app]. You will be the only one who will be allowed to see it and access to it.